# if page refresh again value added?

Tags: php

I'm using the following form in a project. In this form the values are added properly when i submit. but after submit if i refresh the page the existing values are inserted again. i need after submit i refresh the page, the existing values are not added. Please help me.

```
`<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
 <table width="918" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="222" height="300">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="686">
     <table width="331" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="30">
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include("config.php");
$class_section=$_POST['class_section'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql=mysql_query("insert into section(section_id, class_section) values ('', '$class_section')",$conn);
if($sql)
{
echo"<p><center><b><font color='green'>Section Added Successfully!</font></b></center></p>";
}
else
{
echo"<p><center><b><font color='red'>Section Add Failed!</font></b></center></p>";
}
}

?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <table width="331" border="0">
            <tr>
        <td height="47">Class Section/Group</td>
        <td><input name="class_section" type="text"/>       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="33"></td>
         <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD" class="button">             </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>`
```

Comment: From your code, no value is promoted to be inside the input element at all. Probably your browser adds the value again. Try to set the value in your form to nothing, like `value = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

A user initiated request that updates state on the server should always be Post.

Your code also has an SQL injection vulnerability.

Wrap `$class_section` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you use it.